# change a css with javascript in twig

Tags: javascript, css, symfony

I am trying to change a css with a javascript and somehow I get the error that the javascript is null. 
I kinda know its a minor mistake I am doing there but I cant find a way to solve it...

```
<div class="page-content">
{{ page.mixedcontent|raw }}
</div>
<button id="slideshow">Slideshow aktivieren</button>

{% if page.mixedcontent is empty %}
<div id="galleria">
    {% for foto in fotos %}
        <img style="display:none" src="{{ asset('UserUploadFiles/' ~ homepage ~ '/' ~ foto.path) }}" data-title="" data-description="{{ foto.description }}">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
<script>
document.getElementById("#galleria").style.width = "550px";
</script>
<div id="galleria">
    {% for foto in fotos %}
        <img style="display:none" src="{{ asset('UserUploadFiles/' ~ homepage ~ '/' ~ foto.path) }}" data-title="" data-description="{{ foto.description }}">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: why do you modify the css with js ? why don't you set the width in css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
<script>
    $("your element").attr('name off att','value of att');
</script>
```

Hope it will work.Let me know

Answer (score 1):

try this please:

```
{% javascripts %}
    <script>
        document.getElementById("galleria").style.width = "550px";
    </script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

If It doesn't works try this:

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        document.getElementById("galleria").style.width = "550px";
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And remember to remove `#` in front of `galleria`

Answer (score 0):

It either

```
document.getElementById("galleria")
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#galleria")
```